# Rust: strange error " `Slice` is not a trait"

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, traits

I thought I could generalize trait implementations of [`collections::str::StrVector`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/str/trait.StrVector.html) and prepared a patch

- https://github.com/nodakai/rust/commit/d002ac36ae4ced08c682c3a28723cef904ef0027?diff=split

However, my code fails with a strange error message:

```
rustc: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcollections
/home/nodakai/prog/rust-HEAD/src/libcollections/str.rs:140:17: 140:25 error: `Slice` is not a trait
/home/nodakai/prog/rust-HEAD/src/libcollections/str.rs:140 impl<S: Str, V: Slice<S>> StrVector for V {
                                                                           ^~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
make: *** [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/stamp.collections] Error 101
```

I can't understand what is wrong with my code because [the 64th line](https://github.com/nodakai/rust/blob/d002ac36ae4ced08c682c3a28723cef904ef0027/src/libcollections/str.rs#L64) surely `use`s [`core::prelude::Slice`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/prelude/#reexports) which is a re-exported version of [`core::slice::Slice`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/slice/trait.Slice.html).  Moreover playpen compiles the essentially same code fine:

- http://is.gd/T0ZBWK

Comment: http://ideone.com/jc6OLW

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer at Rust IRC:

- https://botbot.me/mozilla/rust/2014-09-27/?msg=22442360&page=21

An enum called `MaybeOwned` is defined in the same file and it has a constructor called `Slice` which shadows the trait `core::prelude::Slice`, hence the error.  I think the error message should be improved...